# Using docker swarm with named volumes

Tags: docker, deployment, swarm, volumes

So how do I get my src files into a named volume as I would with a bound volume in development?

Comment: Usually I'd expect application code to be built into an image; why do you want it in a volume?

Comment: Bound volumes don’t work in a swarm and I’m testing. Not had to create an image yet. I’ll do that thanks